# Using .parent to select divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a [script](http://jsfiddle.net/r0gw8t1b/) which greys out a text area whenever the yes radio button is selected. I would like to modify the jquery script so that the textarea can be in a different div and still be disabled as before.

Looking through the jquery docs it looks to me I can do this using .parent but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

```
<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="yes" />Yes
   <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="no" />No
</div>

<div class="group">
   <textarea rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
```

How can I do this? Or is there a better way?

Edit:

```
    $(function () {

    var $choices = $(".group").find(":radio");
    $choices.on("change", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tarea = $this.closest(".group").next(".group").find("textarea");
        if ($this.val() === "yes") {
            tarea.val('');
            tarea.prop('readonly', true);
            tarea.css('background-color', '#EBEBE4');
        } else {
            tarea.prop('readonly', false);
            tarea.css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added to each `<textarea>` the attribute "trigger". Determinates it's trigger element by name. For example `<textarea data-trigger="choice2">` means `<input name="choice2"/>` change's it's stare (gray/or not).

This way you can add your textarea elements anywhere inside your page without worries.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/r0gw8t1b/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var tarea = $this.closest(".group").next(".group").find("textarea");
```

You can use `next()` to achieve that. It finds the parent `group` and then looks at immediate sibling and looks for `textarea`.

```
<div class="group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice1" value="yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice1" value="no" />No
</div>
<div class="group">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r0gw8t1b/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8nonu9f/) shows how it could be done.

```
$($(this).parent().siblings('div.group')[0]).find('textarea');
```

Find the text area inside the parents siblings of type div.group, and then you can set the css or whichever attributes you want to set as seen in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works well for the selection and disabling the desired text area:

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
   <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="yes" />Yes
   <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="no" />No
</div>

<div class="group">
   <textarea rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function () {     
    $( "input[type='radio']" ).click(function () {
        if ($(this).val()=='yes') {
            $('.group textarea').attr('readonly',true); 
            $('.group textarea').css('background-color', '#f1f1f1');
        } else {
            $('.group textarea').attr('readonly',false); 
            $('.group textarea').css('background-color', '#fff');
        }
    });
});
```